# SELECT records within the past week based on T Z format

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have records stored in my database with a date column that stores values in the T Z format such as

```
2015-06-10T19:15:14.000Z
```

I want to query the table and pull all the records from the past week, normally i would do something like

```
WHERE date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

but with T Z format that doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated thank you

Comment: whic data type is you value stored?

Comment: No good idea to store Dates as formated strings. Looks like you hav eto convert the strings to a date

Comment: It is saved as a text type, it is not possible to change that now with all the records we have already stored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have stored  the date values as a string you should convert using str_to_date

```
 WHERE str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%fZ') > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```